# What are these dark seeds?

Tags: identification, seeds

I found these seeds but I lost their tag. Could you please help me identify which plant these are from?

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us some idea of scale/size thanks

Comment: They look like bell pepper seeds but more oval and have a dark brown/ black colour

Comment: Look locusty. Not Partridge pea, they're squarish.

Comment: Yes they do look like locust or other acacia. They do not look like any capsicum pepper seed that I ever saw however. if they had tags, I doubt they were from a tree unless you collected them yourself. It's unusual to buy tree seeds and more usual to buy immature trees. This also look like coffee beans that have had a chance to fully dry out.

Comment: Try sprouting a couple and see whatthe first true leaves look like

Comment: What kind of seeds do you save? Garden seeds or all types of seeds? Would help if you could narrow it down some. Also, what part of the world are you from?

Answer (score 1):

They look like Ceratonia siliqua seeds but probably are too dark